# Hive ODBC Driver DSN setup Issue

Tags: odbc, driver, hive

I was trying to setup ODBC connection for Hive. I followed the below steps but it didn't worked.

- User DSN-->Add--> Hortonworks Hive ODBC Driver --> and I gave below details
- Host : IP of the Primary name node cluster
- Port:10001
- Server Type : Hive Server 2
- Authentication Mechanism : User Name --> hadoop

While testing the connection, it throws the following error

```
Error:
Driver Version: V1.2.13.1018

Running connectivity tests...

Attempting connection
Failed to establish connection
SQLSTATE: HY000[Hortonworks][Hardy] (34) Error from Hive: connect() failed: errno = 10061.

TESTS COMPLETED WITH ERROR.
```

---

Could you please tell me if the port I use is correct ? If not, what port should I try ? The port 10000 doesn't work either.

Comment: Hi Experts, Kindly help on the above issue.

Answer (score 2):

I am using HDP 2.0 on Windows 2012 R2 Server (Single Node Cluster). I Installed Hive ODBC Driver from Microsoft site. I gave my Host Name and Port `:10001` and user as `hive`. When I installed HDP 2.0 in Win 2012 Server R2, I gave the Hive User Name as `hive`. I am able to connect successfully.

Answer (score 0):

The answer of your problem is that first of all: check on your virtual machine that the port "10000" is added because it's not added by default.

If the port is there, you might check the hive Server if it's running from your virtual machine

I hope it will help.

Answer (score 0):

under the mechanism changed it to user name only.